# how to pass user control in master page?IEnumerable error comes

Tags: c#

i am passing user control to master page, while i am also passing same user control in different pages in application. when i am going to run application i got error on master page : "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Business Layer.Business]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Business Layer.Business'."

Answer (score 0):

change the Model type of the page from the `Business` to `IEnumerable<Business>`

Comment: im sure it wont give the same error if you do it in the right place.. can u please post some more code

Comment: UserControl : 
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<BusinessLayer.Business>" %>
this user control calling view page 
View Page :
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Master.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Business>>"
i am bind list here.
In Master Page :
I am calling that user control : <%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/UserControl/ucCategory.ascx");%>

Answer (score 0):

What the error says, you're passing it a list when it's looking for a single instance of `Business`

Comment: UserControl : <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<BusinessLayer.Business>" %> this user control calling view page View Page : <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Master.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Business>>" i am bind list here. In Master Page : I am calling that user control : <%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/UserControl/ucCategory.ascx");%>

Comment: For starters, it looks like your partial view is expecting a single instance of `Business` and you're passing it nothing, there should be some kind of model here: `<%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/UserControl/ucCategory.ascx", SOMEMODEL);%>`, and secondly, are you rendering the partial view on the Master Page itself? And that view inherits the Master Page? That sounds like infinite loop territory.